# How to discover sony camera through ssdp?

Tags: sony, sony-camera-api

I am trying to discover my Alpha6000 camera through SSDP to get access to the Sony AAPI.  What I did:

- connected my laptop to the camara's wifi (I started it by running the "Smart Remote Embedded" app)
- From my laptop I sent UDP packet to `239.255.255.250:1900` with the payload

  ```
  M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1
  HOST: 239.255.255.250:1900
  MAN: "ssdp:discover"
  MX: seconds to delay response (ex. MX: 1)
  ST: urn:schemas-sony-com:service:ScalarWebAPI:1
  USER-AGENT: OS/version product/version
  ```

But there was no answer from the camera. I suspect that the SSDP server in  the camera is not running.

Comment: Have you tried to use "ST: ssdp:all" instead of "ST: urn:schemas-sony-com:service:ScalarWebAPI:1" to see all ssdp devices on your network ?

Answer (score 0):

1. I assume you mean "SSDP" and not "SSDB"?
2. Have you downloaded the SDK and taken a look at the documentation for the Camera Remote API?  It should contain all you need to know to be able to connect to the camera and control it remotely:
   https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/

Comment: 1. yes, I mean "SSDP"

Comment: 2. yes, I did follow that document.  This is what I [tried](https://gist.github.com/coot/b633f461fba5e8f7bdedfd42ffc5ceb5) (in nodejs)